# Order of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in django

Tags: python, django

the djangobook has this [section](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter16/)

> To activate this CSRF protection, add
>   'django.contrib.csrf.middleware.CsrfMiddleware' to the
>   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting in your settings file. This middleware
>   needs to process the response after SessionMiddleware, so
>   CsrfMiddleware must appear before SessionMiddleware in the list
>   (because the response middleware is processed last-to-first).

however ,[djangoproject page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) tells it different

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', )

It is a bit confusing..Do the CsrfViewMiddleware process the response after SessionMiddleware now?Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Django docs:

> Add the middleware 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your
>   list of middleware classes, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. (It should come before
>   any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt
>   with.)

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-csrf-works

Here's my Middleware list in a freshly generated Django project (1.3.1):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

So, yes, Django processes the CSRF Middleware after the session middleware now.

The Django Book is severely outdated - I wouldn't use it as a resource for learning Django these days. The Django tutorial, on the other hand, is a wonderful resource.

Comment: Is this still applicable today